# When we create Email To Case .. Can we fire Trigger on Email Message Object?

Tags: trigger, email, email2case

```
trigger MiC_Trg_DetectLanguage on EmailMessage (after insert) {

    For( EmailMessage message : Trigger.new)
    {
        String caseId = message.ParentId;
        MethodClass_Future.getLanguage( caseId );
        System.debug('Email Message Recieved');    
    }

}
```

I want the Trigger to fire on getting an email to Case. I have used the standard email to case functionality . Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: what error are you getting? Triggers on `EmailMessage` are fully supported.  Note that the running user will not be you when looking for the debug log if testing. It will be the user configured in Case settings.

Comment: Could you run trigger on EmailMessage for Email to case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code to create Email to case via EmailMessage object..

```
    trigger MyActivityTrigger on EmailMessage(after insert){

        List<Case> newList = [select Status from Case where Id IN (select ParentId from EmailMessage)and Status='Closed'];  
        Case c1=new Case();
         for(EmailMessage em: trigger.new)
         {
            system.debug('Id is '+ em.ParentId);

     for(Case c: newList)
         {
            system.debug('Value is' + c.Status);
     if(c.Status=='Closed')
         {
            system.debug('Came into loop');
            c1.Description='Description1';
            c1.Subject='Subject1';
         }
     }
}
insert c1;
}
```